# Extract U3D object from PDF

Tags: pdf, 3d

PDFs can contain embedded U3D objects.

See this one for example - http://www.carare.eu/eng/content/download/2601/20492/version/1/file/Castle_of_Bouvignes_Belgium_landscape.pdf

Is there a way to extract the .U3D object from a PDF so that it can be viewed and edited in another program?

I've tried opening the PDF in Acroread - it renders the 3D object, but there's no way to export it.

[image]

PDFedit doesn't seem to have any support.

Would be very handy if it were Linux command line - but that's not essential.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is kinda old, but nonetheless:

I managed to extract u3d objects with [pdf-parser.py](http://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/pdf-tools/).

```
pdf-parser.py -t /3D input.pdf
```

gives you the object ID(s). Then use

```
pdf-parser.py -o $ID -d output.u3d input.pdf
```

to extract the given object. BTW pypy significantly improves the speed over cpython.

If someone finds a way to convert the u3d file to something usable, please reply.

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you. Just need to find a way to view the U3D now :-)

Comment: There are a few commercial products claiming compaibility. I tried the trial of [Simlab Composer](http://www.simlab-soft.com), it was able to open the files. But I need to convert them. I didn't find a free solution to do so. _Universal3D_ doesn't seem to be that universal...